# hide form without hurt in it's functionalities c++ builder borland

Tags: forms, c++builder, c++builder-6

I'm using Borland C++Builder 6.  I would like to hide a form but I want all its functionalities to remain as is.

The problem is that if I change the `Visible` property of the form, some 
things go wrong.

In addition, I can't use the `Hide()` function since it contains code which closes the window.

Comment: If you want to Hide your forms they must be coded so the do not access visual stuff while hidden otherwise exceptions and other weird stuff happens. Try minimizing instead that should be safe.

Comment: "*do not access visual stuff while hidden otherwise exceptions and other weird stuff happens*" - such as? I have never run into this problem.  It might be specific to the particular UI controls being used.

Comment: "*The problem is that if I change the Visible property of the form, some things go wrong*" - like what exactly?  Please be more specific.